Taylor expansion of $x^2/(k+x^2)$
I'm trying to write down a formula for the Taylor expansion of $x^2/(k+x^2)$ around $x=z$. The Taylor expansion for $x/(k+x)$ around $x=z$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{k+x} = \frac{z}{k+z} + k \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j+1} \frac{\left( x-z\right)^{j}}{\left( k+z\right)^{j+1}}.
\end{align*}
Expanding around $z^2$ gives:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2}{k+x^2} &= \frac{z^2}{k+z^2} + k \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j+1} \frac{\left( x^2-z^2\right)^{j}}{\left( k+z^2\right)^{j+1}}\\
&= \frac{z^2}{k+z^2} + k \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j+1} \frac{\left( x-z\right)^{j}\left( x+z\right)^{j}}{\left( k+z^2\right)^{j+1}}.
\end{align*}
What I would like to do now is expand
\begin{align*}
(x+z)^j = (x -z +2z)^j = \sum_{l=0}^{j} \binom{j}{l} (x-z)^l (2z)^{j-l} 
\end{align*}
and rearrange in the sum above to find that the coefficient of $(x-z)^m$ is the following:
\begin{align*}
\left[(x-z)^m\right]&=k\sum_{j+l=m} (-1)^{j+1}\binom{j}{l}\frac{(2z)^{j-l}}{\left( k+z^2\right)^{j+1}}\\
  &=k\sum_{j=\lceil m/2 \rceil}^{m} (-1)^{j+1}\binom{j}{m-j}\frac{(2z)^{2j-m}}{\left( k+z^2\right)^{j+1}}.
\end{align*}
However, I don't know if the rearrangement is valid, since I'm splitting up the terms of the original convergent series. Is there a way to see that this new series converges? Alternatively, is there a more direct way to figure out the Taylor expansion for this function?

Let $x=z+u$, then you want to get Taylor series for
$$
\frac{(z+u)^2}{k+(z+u)^2}=1-\sqrt{k} f(u)
$$
where
$$
f(u)=\frac{\sqrt{k}}{u^2+2zu+z^2+k}
=\frac{i}{2}\left[\frac1{u+z+i\sqrt{k}}-\frac1{u+z-i\sqrt{k}}.\right]
$$
Now use the fact that for any $c\ne 0$ and $|u|<|c|$
$$
\frac1{u-c}=-\frac1c\left[1+\frac{u}{c}+\frac{u^2}{c^2}+\dots\right]
$$
to get that
\begin{align}
f(u)&=\frac{i}{2}\left[
\frac1{z+i\sqrt{k}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^n}{(-(z+i\sqrt{k}))^n} 
-
\frac1{z-i\sqrt{k}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^n}{(-(z-i\sqrt{k}))^n} 
\right]
\\ &
=\frac{i}{2}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n (-1)^n \left[ \frac{(z-i\sqrt{k})^{n+1}-(z+i\sqrt{k})^{n+1}}
{(z^2+k)^{n+1}} 
\right]
\end{align}
which holds as long as $|u|<\sqrt{z^2+k}$.
